# Angular 2 app not running

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 2 and i am trying run sample applications from github.

I downloaded the sample application from the url **https://github.com/AngularShowcase/angular2-sample-app**

When I am trying to serve the application its giving me the following error as shown below.

**"The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'"**

Can anybody please help me to resolve the error and run my application.

I tried even deleting node_modules folder and again running npm install.

I also tried "npm uninstall -g angular-cli" " npm cache clean" and "npm install"

### The below shown is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "material2-srcs",
  "description": "Material Design components for Angular",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/material2",
  "bugs": "https://github.com/angular/material2/issues",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angular/material2.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngc -p angular.tsconfig.json",
    "build": "gulp :publish:build-releases",
    "demo-app": "gulp serve:devapp",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "tslint": "gulp lint",
    "stylelint": "gulp lint",
    "e2e": "gulp e2e",
    "deploy": "gulp deploy:devapp",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "docs": "gulp docs",
    "api": "gulp api-docs"
  },
  "version": "5.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 5.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "5.1.1",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.43",
    "tsickle": "0.24.x",
    "tslib": "1.7.1",
    "typescript": "2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/bazel": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "5.0.1",
    "@bazel/ibazel": "0.1.1",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "1.1.1",
    "@types/chalk": "0.4.31",
    "@types/fs-extra": "4.0.3",
    "@types/glob": "5.0.33",
    "@types/gulp": "3.8.32",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.6.0",
    "@types/merge2": "0.3.30",
    "@types/minimist": "1.2.0",
    "@types/node": "7.0.21",
    "@types/run-sequence": "0.0.29",
    "autoprefixer": "6.7.6",
    "axe-core": "2.3.1",
    "axe-webdriverjs": "1.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "dgeni": "0.4.9",
    "dgeni-packages": "0.22.0",
    "firebase": "4.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "5.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "3.11.0",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "glob": "7.1.2",
    "google-closure-compiler": "20170409.0.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "0.3.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "3.3.1",
    "gulp-cli": "1.3.0",
    "gulp-connect": "5.0.0",
    "gulp-conventional-changelog": "1.1.3",
    "gulp-dom": "0.9.17",
    "gulp-flatten": "0.3.1",
    "gulp-highlight-files": "0.0.5",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "3.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "2.0.2",
    "gulp-markdown": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "3.1.0",
    "gulp-transform": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "3.0.8",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "highlight.js": "9.11.0",
    "http-rewrite-middleware": "0.1.6",
    "image-diff": "1.6.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "7.4.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-browserstack-launcher": "1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-sauce-launcher": "1.2.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "madge": "2.2.0",
    "magic-string": "0.22.4",
    "minimatch": "3.0.4",
    "minimist": "1.2.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "protractor": "5.2.0",
    "request": "2.83.0",
    "resolve-bin": "0.4.0",
    "rollup": "0.41.6",
    "rollup-plugin-alias": "1.3.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "3.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "scss-bundle": "2.0.1-beta.7",
    "selenium-webdriver": "3.6.0",
    "sorcery": "0.10.0",
    "stylelint": "7.12.0",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tsconfig-paths": "2.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.8.0",
    "tsutils": "2.6.0",
    "typescript": "2.5.2",
    "uglify-js": "2.8.14",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: What are your `node` and `npm` versions?

Comment: C:\Angular\material_angular>node -v
v6.11.4

C:\Angular\material_angular>npm -v
3.10.10

Comment: these are my versions for node and npm

Comment: did you run angular-cli by --open command?

Comment: make sure you are using supported version of node JS and there are some complaints with node versions also.

Comment: the node version in my package.json is     "node": ">= 5.4.1"... and in my terminal its v6.11.4..

Comment: should i change it to the 6.11.4

Answer (score 0):

try installing the latest version of the cli using

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

and if its still giving you the same issue then
modify your package.json file to `"@angular/cli": "^1.6.0","@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",` in devDependencies.
then run

```
npm install
```

Comment: please can you help me sending me a sample angular 2 application with angular material.